# Reserve a table

Tags: traducción

How to write politely this text in Spanish?

"Hello, 
I would like to reserve a best table for two people on February 25 at 7:00 p.m., please. I want to write an article and share the experience in my travel blog. Thank you very much in advance."

My attempt:

*Hola! Buen día. Me gustaría reservar una mejor mesa para dos personas el 25 de febrero a las 7:00 hrs, por favor. Quiero escribir un artículo y compartir la experiencia en mi blog de viajes. Agradezco de antemano sus atenciones. Jack*

Comment: Hi and welcome to Spanish SE. It would be nice if you tried yourself first. Do you have any specific question? If you just want a translation, this might be off-topic here. Thank you.

Comment: Hola! 

Buen día. Me gustaría reservar una mejor mesa para dos personas el 25 de febrero a las 7:00 hrs, por favor. 
Quiero escribir un artículo y compartir la experiencia en mi blog de viajes.
Agradezco de antemano sus atenciones.

Jack

Comment: That's much better. If you don't mind, I'll include it in the question. You can always edit yuor own question.

Comment: I think you mean *one of the best tables*. // Why do they need to know about the travel blog?  Food critics don't announce their identity, and in fact if they are well known, and it's a high profile restaurant, they may well wear a disguise.  I think you could leave that out.  Go for polite and minimalist.  Restaurant workers are busy people.  Regarding the minimalism: "very much" and "in advance" are too much in English or Spanish.

Comment: I voted to close; you might wonder why, when you kindly shared your attempt to translate, as someone requested.  Well, proofreading isn't allowed; however, specific questions are.  Here's an example of how one might rescue a question of this type (but it doesn't just depend on me): *Is the following polite enough/too ingratiating for the culture in [name of location or region]?*  People will say yes or no, and give a reason, but will probably slip in some text corrections as well (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

> Me gustaría reservar una mesa cómoda y con buena ubicación para dos personas el día 25 de febrero a las 19:00 horas, por favor.

In my opinion this will be a polite way to say what you asked. I wrote 19:00, but if you prefer, you can use 7:00. The intention is to be clear if you want to book in the evening, nonetheless is not a rule that you have to use necessarily the 24 hours time.

Comment: Thank you Claudia Sanchez and all contrubutors! You are very helpful!